# How to auto login to a new people soft profile using web logic

Tags: web-services, web-applications, peoplesoft

How to embed a user name and password into the URL so that the page will be
 redirected without the user having to login

Comment: Passwords can't be embedded in URLs.  Being able to do so would be a huge security flaw.

Comment: not into the url (get) but you can use POST (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can POST to your URL using:

```
<input id="userid" name="userid" type="text"  value="PS" size="15" tabindex="2">
<input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="pure-input-2-3" size="15" tabindex="3" value ="PS">
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is a bad idea because URL parameters are saved in browser history and are visible in the address bar, but it isn't right for us to judge your question since we don't know your use case. It is entirely possible that your solution is secure and safe and part of an automated process communicating through a secure channel.

PeopleSoft automatically understands POST parameters, so no special logic necessary for a POST request. A GET request is also possible, but requires some work on your end. The easiest way would be to use a ServletFilter or some other proxy program in front of PeopleSoft to rewrite the GET request as a POST request. Another alternative is to use a public user ID with a public iScript to SwitchUser. Signon PeopleCode may work as well.

If you create a process for logging in via GET, other users may have access to the same approach, so just be sure to secure your GET process as well.

Whatever you do, be extremely careful. I have known people to write Signon PeopleCode that ALWAYS evaluates to True. Obviously, this completely eliminates security. If you write Signon PeopleCode, be sure to keep it simple.